# measurable function of two variables that depends only on the second argument is measurable wrt. its second argument.

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

Let $(E,\mathcal{E})$, $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ and $(G,\mathcal{G})$ be measurable spaces and consider a measurable function $X:(E\times \Omega, \,\mathcal{E}\otimes\mathcal{F})\to (G,\,\mathcal{G})$ such that X depends only on its second argument, i.e. $X(y,\omega)=X(\omega),\forall y\in E\,\forall \omega\in\Omega$.

Fix now $y\in E$ and define $\tilde{X}:\Omega\to G,\,\omega\mapsto X(y,\omega)$.

> Show that $\tilde{X}$ is measurable wrt. $\mathcal{E}$.

---

My attempt: Fix $A\in\mathcal{G}$ then $\tilde{X}^{-1}(a)=\{\omega\in\Omega:X(y,\omega)\in A\}$. We know that $X^{-1}(A)\in \mathcal{E}\otimes\mathcal{F}$. I have then tried writing $\tilde{X}^{-1}(A)=X^{-1}(A)\cap\{ (x,\omega)\in E\times\Omega: x=y\}$ but that's where I got stuck. I would somehow like to go from general elements of $\mathcal{E}\otimes \mathcal{F}$ to those of $\mathcal{E}\times \mathcal{F}$ in order to conclude.

Answer (score 1):

Check that $E \times \overline X^{-1} (A) =X^{-1} (A)$. Can you finish?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately I cannot finish: Now $E\times \tilde{X}^{-1}(A)\in \mathcal{E}\otimes\mathcal{F}$ with $E\in\mathcal{E}$. How can I use this to reason that $E\times \tilde{X}^{-1}(A)\in \mathcal{E}\times \mathcal{F}$?

Comment: @test123 Are you familiar with 'sections' of sets in a product space? If $A\times B$ is measurable in a product space then $A$ and $B$ are measurable sets (provided they are non-empty sets) because $A$ is the section of $A \times B$ by any point of $B$  and $B$ is the section of $A \times B$ by any point of $A$. (Ref: Fubini's Theorem in , say, Rudin's RCA).